# Expand on checking a checkbox

Tags: jquery

There are some boxes and options in post section of my website that by checking some of the checkboxes it *expands* and shows some other options and fields.

But when I use this method in jquery to check them, they won't expand how ever they are checked:

```
jQuery('#input_id').prop('checked', true);
```

I didn't check but maybe they expand on a *onclick* action. I wanna know if there is a way to achieve that.

Comment: you mean they expand on `click` but not when you set by `.prop` ?

Comment: What code do you use to expand the box?

Comment: Have you tried: `document.getElementById("#input_id").onclick();`?

Comment: @Sergio, yes! they expand on manual checking by mouse and not with `prop` method.

Comment: @pattyd! I don't use any code for expanding!

Comment: What? Then they shouldn't expand. Are you working with a team? Maybe a team member added the expanding code? There must be some code that controls the expanding, as this is not normal behavior.

Comment: @pattyd, no. see what I stated is different. in fact i'm using wordpress. there are some meta boxes in add new/edit post section that by checking them, they will expand. now I want to expand them by jquery so I check them by `prop` method! they get checked but not expand!

Comment: You need to bind to `change` not click. `$('.selector').on('change', function() {`